# Shadow effect in card

Tags: react-native

How to get this effect?

[image]

Ready Card in NativeBase not work

```
flex: 1,
flexDirection: 'row',
backgroundColor: '#eaf6f8',
borderRadius: 10,
shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
shadowOpacity: .3,
shadowRadius: 3,
elevation: 1,
borderWidth: 3,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
elevation : 5
```

or if you want more shadow increase the number